# Sin conexión tras instalar VirtualBox

Tags: configuración, virtualbox

Hola a todos a ver si podéis ayudarme porque me estoy volviendo loco, tengo el VirtualBox instalado es la versión 4.2, pero por asuntos de trabajo necesito instalar la 5.2.22 pero al instalar el programa se estropea la conexión a internet, es una conexión inalambrica, lo chocante es que tiene todas las rayitas de conexión y todo parece que vaya bien con excepción que menciona donde ponía "conectado" lo cambia por "acceso limitado" con lo cual no puedo navegar por internet.

El propio VirtualBox al instalar pone un mensaje que puede dejarte sin conexión pero a modo temporal... temporal yo lo entiendo como unos minutos no? porque he estado mucho rato sin internet. Llevo todo el día restaurando y probando cosas no se... estoy desesperado porque es por el trabajo, mañana tengo que empezar y no lo tengo instalado.

También me ha ocurrido lo mismo al desinstalar la versión que tenía. Ya que una de las veces probé a desinstalarla antes de instalar la nueva, y no me hizo falta instalar la nueva porque ya me quedé sin interent simplemente desinstalando la versión que tengo.

Tengo un Windows 7.

---------------------- Editado---------------------------------------------

Por lo que veo el problema es que cuando desinstalo o instalo el virtualbox coge una ip fuera de la red, igual que una ip del servidor DNS rara y una puerta de enlace sin nada.

He probado de configurar la ip para la conexión de forma manual y tampoco funciona.

Adjunto el ipconfig de antes de instalar virtualbox y despues de hacerlo, por si puede ayudar.

Antes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tras instalar nueva versión virtual box:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un saludo.

Comment: Por lo que veo el problema es que cuando desinstalo o instalo el virtualbox coge una ip fuera de la red, igual que una ip del servidor DNS rara y una puerta de enlace sin nada.

Comment: win 7 tiene algunos temas en cuanto a prioridad en las conexiones, fijate si (luego de instalar VBox) en los adaptadores no te ha quedado el adaptador virtual por encima del wifi

Comment: He llegado a desconectar el adaptador, como no utilizaba el programa... pero si fuera lo que tú dices como cambio esa prioridad, donde se hace eso?

Comment: no tengo a mano un win7 pero encontré este enlace: https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/2526067

Comment: Gracias, pero tras mucho mirar por la red y probar las soluciones que me encontraba, al final opté por reinstalar el SO ahora funciona todo bien con todos los programas que quiero instalar